# How do I make the procedure with multiple ifs shorter and efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this procedure which basically checks the ledgertype and on the basis of that, it picks the data from relevant tables.

The main table i.e. GLedger stores the transactions from different modules and differentiates on the basis of ledger type id.

Is there any way to make this procedure shorter and more efficient?

The actual query is longer than this but I trimmed it for posting.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_General_Ledger_Reported2] -- exec Sp_General_Ledger_Reported2 1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
        @CompanyID INT = NULL
        ,@GLAccountNo VARCHAR(30) = NULL
        ,@GLAccountNoFrom VARCHAR(30) = NULL
        ,@FromDate VARCHAR(30) = ''
        ,@ToDate VARCHAR(30) = ''
        --Select * From GLedger
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET @FromDate = CASE 
                WHEN @FromDate = ''
                    THEN '1/1/2000'
                ELSE @FromDate
                END
        SET @ToDate = CASE 
                WHEN @ToDate = ''
                    THEN '1/1/2030'
                ELSE @ToDate
                END
    
        IF (
                @FromDate != NULL
                OR @FromDate != ''
                AND @ToDate != NULL
                OR @ToDate != ''
                )
        BEGIN
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,'Not Assigned' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,V.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,V.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,V.InvoiceDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,V.ClearingDocumentNo AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,V.TEXT AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Vendorinvoice V ON G.MainID = v.VendorInvoice_ID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '1'
            LEFT JOIN PVTypes ON V.Transaction_ID = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    G.GLAccountNo BETWEEN @GLAccountNo
                        AND @GLAccountNoFrom
                    )
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,B.BranchCode
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,'' AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,'' AS 'Document Type'
                ,'' AS 'PostingDate'
                ,'' AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,VI.Assignment AS 'Assignment'
                ,D.DepartmentCode AS 'Department'
                ,S.Code AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,VI.TEXT AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Branch B ON G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
            INNER JOIN VendorInvoiceTransactions VI ON G.SubID = VI.VendorTransactionsID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '2'
            LEFT JOIN Department D ON G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
            LEFT JOIN ServiceLineMaster S ON G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON VI.Project_ID = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,B.BranchCode
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,S.InvoiceNo AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,'' AS 'Document Type'
                ,S.PODate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,S.PODate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,S.AccountingAssignment AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,S.TextDescription AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Branch B ON G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
            --inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
            INNER JOIN Sales S ON G.MainID = S.SalesID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '3'
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON S.AccAssignmentWBSElementID = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            --inner join Department D on S.AccAssignmentDepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
            --inner join ServiceLineMaster SE on S.AccAssignmentServiceLineID = SE.ServiceLineID
            --inner join Projects P on S.AccAssignmentWBSElementID = P.Project_ID
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,B.BranchCode
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,'' AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,'' AS 'Document Type'
                ,'' AS 'PostingDate'
                ,'' AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,D.DepartmentCode AS 'Department'
                ,S.Name AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,'' AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Branch B ON G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
            --inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
            INNER JOIN SalesTransactions ST ON G.SubID = ST.SalesTransactionID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '4'
            LEFT JOIN Department D ON G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
            LEFT JOIN ServiceLineMaster S ON G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON ST.ProjectID = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,'Not Assigned' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,TAIP.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,TAIP.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,TAIP.DocumentDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,TAIP.DocHeaderText AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN tblAccountsInvoicePayable TAIP ON G.MainID = TAIP.PayableInvoice_ID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '5'
            INNER JOIN PVTypes ON TAIP.Type = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,'Not Assigned' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,RVI.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,RVI.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,RVI.DocumentDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,RVI.DocHeaderText AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN ReceviableInvoice RVI ON G.MainID = RVI.ReceviableInvoice_ID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '7'
            INNER JOIN PVTypes ON RVI.Type = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,PDHD.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,PDHD.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,PDHD.DocumentDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,PDHD.Assignment AS 'Assignment'
                ,D.DepartmentCode AS 'Department'
                ,S.Name AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,PDHD.DocHeaderText AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN PostDocumentHeaderData PDHD ON G.MainID = PDHD.VendorPVId
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '8'
            INNER JOIN PVTypes ON PDHD.TypeID = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN Department D ON G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
            LEFT JOIN ServiceLineMaster S ON G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON PDHD.Projects = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,VPHD.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,VPHD.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,VPHD.DocumentDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,VPHD.Assignment AS 'Assignment'
                ,D.DepartmentCode AS 'Department'
                ,S.Name AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,VPHD.DocHeaderText AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN VendorPVHeaderData VPHD ON G.MainID = VPHD.VendorPVId
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '8'
            INNER JOIN PVTypes ON VPHD.TypeID = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN Department D ON G.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
            LEFT JOIN ServiceLineMaster S ON G.ServiceLineID = S.ID
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON VPHD.Projects = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,B.BranchCode
                ,'Not Assigned' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,V.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,V.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,V.InvoiceDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,V.ClearingDocumentNo AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'Offsettingacctno'
                ,V.TEXT AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Branch B ON G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
            --inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
            INNER JOIN Vendorinvoice V ON G.MainID = v.VendorInvoice_ID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '9'
            INNER JOIN PVTypes ON V.Transaction_ID = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,B.BranchCode
                ,P.ProjectCode AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,S.InvoiceNo AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,'' AS 'Document Type'
                ,S.PODate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,S.PODate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,'' AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,S.AccountingAssignment AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'Offsettingacctno'
                ,S.TextDescription AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Branch B ON G.BusinessArea = B.BranchCode
            --inner join LedgerTypes L on G.LedgerType_ID = L.ID
            INNER JOIN Sales S ON G.MainID = S.SalesID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '9'
            LEFT JOIN Projects P ON S.AccAssignmentWBSElementID = p.Project_ID
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Com.CompanyCode
                ,G.BusinessArea
                ,'Not Assigned' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,G.GLAccountNo
                ,COA.ShortText
                ,G.DocCurrency
                ,G.DocCurrencyAmount
                ,G.Currency AS 'localCurrecny'
                ,G.Amount AS 'LocalAmount'
                ,V.Reference AS 'Reference'
                ,cast(G.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'DocumentNumber'
                ,PVTypes.Type AS 'Document Type'
                ,V.PostingDate AS 'PostingDate'
                ,V.InvoiceDate AS 'DocmentDate'
                ,G.PK
                ,V.ClearingDocumentNo AS 'Clearing Document'
                ,'' AS 'Assignment'
                ,'' AS 'Department'
                ,'' AS 'ServiceLineCode'
                ,'' AS 'ProjectCode'
                ,'' AS 'OffSettingAcctNo'
                ,V.TEXT AS 'Text'
            FROM GLedger G
            INNER JOIN Company Com ON G.CompanyID = Com.CompanyID
            INNER JOIN Vendorinvoice V ON G.MainID = v.VendorInvoice_ID
                AND G.LedgerType_ID = '10'
            LEFT JOIN PVTypes ON V.Transaction_ID = PVTypes.Id
            LEFT JOIN COA ON G.GLAccountNo = COA.GLAccount
            WHERE (G.CompanyID = @CompanyID)
                AND (
                    G.GLAccountNo BETWEEN @GLAccountNo
                        AND @GLAccountNoFrom
                    )
                AND (
                    (
                        G.GLAccountNo >= @GLAccountNo
                        OR @GLAccountNo IS NULL
                        )
                    AND (
                        G.GLAccountNo <= @GLAccountNoFrom
                        OR @GLAccountNoFrom IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                    Convert(DATE, G.DATETIME, 101) BETWEEN Convert(DATE, @FromDate, 101)
                        AND Convert(DATE, @ToDate, 101)
                    )
        END

    END
        --Select * from Projects
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s: done.. thanks

Comment: Do you want to make it `shorter`, then please say why, do you want to make it `more efficient`, then the question arises is it not efficient.  Remember, shorter is totally different from `more efficient`.  I only would put some comments before every `SELECT` to indicate some info on that part of the statement.

Comment: shorter, because it's hard to debug and maintain.

Comment: Refactoring that, if indeed its possible to do so, is not really a question as such. Its actually a fairly large job which you are asking others to do for you. I suggest hiring a consultant.

Comment: @Testingapps *don't* use strings to pass dates. Use the proper type, `date`. That's a bigger problem than the catch-all query. Strings need to be parsed and can *easily* lead to failed queries or bad data. What does `4/7` mean? April 7th or July 4? You can never know - you *can't* bee sure that 101 is the correct format. `date` and all date-related types have no format, they are unambiguous binary values. Just *don't use the wrong types*

Comment: As for the catch-all query, don't use it. catch-all queries [cause performance problems](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) because SQL Server caches the execution plan the first time a stored procedure is called and reuses it. If you pass a `null` for a parameter, the server may create a plan that scans the table instead of seeking an index and use *that* the next time you call the stored procedure with an actual value

Comment: `@FromDate != NULL` doesn't work as well as [`is not null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If it _did_ work then `@FromDate != NULL OR @FromDate != ''` would be equivalent to `true` since there are few values that are equal to two different values at the same time. Of course, if `@FromDate` was supposed to contain a date it should be a <drumroll> [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), not a `VarChar(30)`.

Comment: hi thanks guys, my question is, will UNION ALL slow it down? is there any other alternative>

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, all your select statements start from `GLedger` and company tables, filtered on the same time period.

You could start by inserting all that filtered data in a temp table and running all the queries on that temp table instead of the full table.
Depending on your data (my company also has a accounting app), if you index the table properly, it will be faster as well.

Comment: Not really an answer, more a tip (which belongs in a comment).

Comment: This helps with a completely different problem, not the multiple filters and dates. Accounting applications make updates to the tables all the time so a heavy analytic query will be blocked by the updates. The solution is *NOT* to use an unindexed temp table, it's using a *separate* reporting database or OLAP cube, which all accounting applications provide. Some of them may offer that as an extra that management didn't want to pay for, so developers have to build them themselves. A temp table though is never a good solution

Comment: Querying an indexed table multiple times is orders of magnitude faster than copying the data into a temporary table and performing queries without indexing. If the temp table is indexed - well, you're partway to the reporting database. Why not make a *proper* reporting database that only needs to be updated with new records on a schedule instead of creating the temp table from scratch at query time?

Comment: yes, a separate server / database is a good thing to have. One could also use MSSQLs columnstore for running reports on a transactional database. But the request is for making the code shorter and easier to maintain. for me, that implies that those tables do not hold millions of rows. I'd say my answer for the specific request but i'm not going to argue that it could've been a comment. Thx.

Comment: hi thanks, would the union all slow down execution?

Comment: it really depends on your data and business requirements. in our case it has been working great for the past 5 years, but we rarely have more than 1M rows in the tables. the insert in a temp table is not costly because we filter most of it out, and only select the columns needed for our reports.